# Как передавать не только названия товара но и категории в заказе Woocomerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

при заказе Woocommerce заявка попадает на е-майл администратора где видно какие товары покупал пользователь. Возможно ли сделать что бы они отправлялись вместе с названием категории?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сделать так

```
function add_term_description_mail( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
    $items = $order->get_items();
    
    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        // Get terms
        $terms = get_the_terms($item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat');
                
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) { ?>
               <br> Категория: <?php echo $term->name;  
             } 
    }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'add_term_description_mail', 20, 4 );
```

https://wp-kama.ru/plugin/woocommerce/hook/woocommerce_order_item_meta_end

Подробный гайд по хукам письма [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Плюсую за картинку, но стоит ещё давать ссылки на оф. маны.